# My C# grading program keep outputting the same result

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I just started C# and was making this very simple C# program to print a grade according to the inputed marks.

Here's my program:

```
    class data
{

    int marks;
    public void input()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your marks");
        marks = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());



    }

    public void output()
    {
        if (marks >= 75)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Merit");
        }
        else if (marks < 75)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Distiction");
        }
        else if (marks < 65)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Credit");
        }
        else if (marks < 55)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pass");
        }
        else Console.WriteLine("Fail");


    }
}
}
```

And here's the main:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        data obj1 = new data();
        obj1.input();
        obj1.output();
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
}
```

Problem is it keeps outputting "Distinction" as the grade no matter what input I give. What am I doing wrong?

Edit - Fail marks is below 40

Comment: Have you tried *debugging* the program?

Comment: Well, if a number is less 55 it´s certainly also smaller 75, which is checked before.

Comment: your if-else logic seems buggy..

Comment: You mean 75 or above is not returning `merit`? Everything below will indeed return Distinction, because of the arrangment of your ifs statement. Everything that is not larger than or equal to 75 will be lower than 75 and all the other if statements don't make any sense

Comment: Your logic is bad.  The first two conditions will cover every possible value of `marks`.

Comment: The first thing your code checks for is if the input is greater than, or equal to 75.  Then it checks if the input is less than 75.  If you put 74, 64, -1, 0, etc **they are all lower than 75 and will satisfy that if condition**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have failed to use proper ranges; since the `marks < 75` block comes before `marks < 65` block, and for all cases where `marks <65` (and so on) are also true for `marks < 75`, your code will always stop at `marks < 75` and thus output `Distinction`.

Not seeing an obvious reason it won't output `Merit` for properly high values, however

Comment: Probably because the conversion failed. He should use `Int32.TryParse()` or `Int32.Parse()`. The variable is of type `Int32` and not `Int16`.

And he should print the value for debug purposes, to see what the value is.

Answer (score 2):

For all marks entry below 75 it makes 2nd condition true, that's why you get distinction every time. Change your output function to this

```
    public void output()
    {
        if (marks >= 75)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Merit");
        }
        else if (marks >= 65 && marks < 75)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Distiction");
        }
        else if (marks >= 55 && marks < 65)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Credit");
        }
        else if (marks >= 40 && marks < 55) // Here 40 is passing marks. You've set up of your own
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pass");
        }
        else Console.WriteLine("Fail");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your second if statement, (marks < 75) includes all the statements below it. For example, if marks < 75 is correct, then that statement will run, and no other statements will be checked like marks < 65 or marks < 55 because marks < 75 includes them. You need to do:

```
if (marks >= 75){
    Console.WriteLine("Merit");
}else if (marks < 55){
    Console.WriteLine("Pass");
}else if (marks < 65){
    Console.WriteLine("Credit");
}else if (marks < 75){
    Console.WriteLine("Distiction");
}else 
    Console.WriteLine("Fail");
```

Comment: There's still an issue, anything less than 55 still says its "pass"

Comment: What do you want it to say? In your original program that's what you had it say for <55.

Comment: @PhoenixFireFlite The issue is that you never get to the else.  The OP needs to tell us the boundary between Pass and Fail

Comment: What do you consider a fail?

Comment: Yup, thanks. Now I get the issue with the fail marks. My bad, I have to say the fail mark is below 40.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you have expected:

```
public void output()
{
    if (marks >= 75)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Merit");
    }
    else if (marks < 55)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Pass");
    }
    else if (marks < 65)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Credit");
    }
    else if (marks < 75)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Distiction");
    }
    else Console.WriteLine("Fail");
}
```

P.S. Please begin classes and methods names with an uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having a difficult time trying to resolve your logic - I'll take a hit in negative votes just to get a better feel for your intent.

But I think it's good for you to see that if asked to check if a number sits "between two numbers", you can construct an IF to check only for the lower boundary.

**Edit - Fail Mark below 40**

```
  if (marks >= 75) Console.WriteLine("Merit");
  else if (marks >= 65) Console.WriteLine("Distinction");
  else if (marks >= 55) Console.WriteLine("Credit");
  else if (marks >= 40) Console.WriteLine("Pass");
  else Console.WriteLine("Fail");
```